# Drop Route Values on Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

So, I've been trying for a few hours now to workaround something that should theoretically be very simple. Let's take this sample url:

```
http://sample.com/products/in/texas/dallas
```

This maps onto a specific route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "products",
    "products/in/{state}/{city}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "List", state = UrlParameter.Optional, city = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

In my action method, I can do lookups to make sure "texas" and "dallas" exist, and that "dallas" exists within Texas. That's all fine and dandy. However, in the situation where the city doesnt exist (either because the geo is incorrect, or mispelled), I want it to back up the state level. Example:

```
http://sample.com/products/in/texas/dallax
```

That should issue a redirect to

```
http://sample.com/products/in/texas
```

The "easy" way to do this was to simply issue a Redirect call like so:

```
return Redirect("/products/in/" + stateName);
```

However, I'm trying to decouple this from the URL structure; for example, if we ever decided to change how the route looks (say, change the pattern to `products/around/{state}/{city}`), then I would have to know that I need to make updates to this controller to fix the URL redirect.

If I can make a solution that just inspects the route values and can figure things out, then I don't have to worry if I change the route pattern, because the route values could still be figured out.

Ideally, I would have liked to do something like this:

```
return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Products", action = "List", state = state });
```

(Note, that is is a simplified example; the "required" route pieces like controller name and action method name would be determined by Generic argument and Expression inspection respectively).

That actually performs the redirect, **HOWEVER**, the route values from the current request get appended onto the redirect and thus you get in a redirect loop (note that I didn't include the city route value in the route object). **How do I stop the "city" route value from being included in this redirect?**

I've tried the following things to get rid of the route value:

1. Compose my own `RouteValueDictionary` / anonymous route data object and pass that to the overload of `RedirectToRoute`.
2. Create my own action result to inspect `RouteTable.Routes` and find the route myself, and do the replacement of the tokens myself. This seems the most "kludgy", and would seem to be re-inventing the wheel.
3. Make a method like `RedirectWithout` that takes a key value and calls `RedirectToRouteResult.RouteValues.Remove(key)` - which also didnt work.
4. I've also attempted to add a null value for the key I don't want to add; however, this alters the route to something that isnt correct - ie `new { controller = "Products", action = "List", state = stateName, city = (string)null }` issues a redirect to `/Products/List?state=Texas` which is not the right URL.

It all seems to stem from the RedirectToRoute taking the current request context to construct the virtual path data. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using T4MVC, you should be able to do something like this:

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Products.List(state, null));
```

Have you tried this?

```
return RedirectToRoute(new 
{
    controller = "Products", 
    action = "List", 
    state = state,
    city = null, 
});
```

**Reply to comments**

Maybe MVC is confused because your optional parameter is not at the end. The below should work with the above `RedirectToRoute` that specifies `city = null`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "products",
    "products/in/{state}/{city}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Products",
        action = "List",
        // state = UrlParameter.Optional, // only let the last parameter be optional
        city = UrlParameter.Optional 
    });
```

You can then add another route to handle URL's where `state` is optional:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, // I never name my routes
    "products/in/{state}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Products",
        action = "List",
        state = UrlParameter.Optional 
    });
```

Comment: Indeed, I've tried the attempt to make the route value null (for example, `city = (string)null`. That results in a valid redirect without the parameter, but on the incorrect URL.

Comment: If it doesn't redirect to /products/in/texas, what URL does it redirect to?

Comment: Also, despite my arguments for it's usage, I've been overruled on T4MVC. =/

Comment: `/products/list?state=Texas`. Now I figure that might be because I didn't specify the route name I used in MapRoute, so when I do `RedirectToRoute(RouteNames.Product, new { blah })` it throws an exception that it could not find a route matching the supplied values.

Comment: Another route may end up being the direction I go with how frustrating this is becoming =/

Comment: The reason I never name my routes is because it forces me to not use the RedirectToRoute overloads (and HtmlHelper/UrlHelper overloads) that take a route name parameter. You should be able to do this without messing with any route name stuff.

Comment: Im assuming you simply let T4MVC do it's code generation thing? Honestly, I must be overlooking something small to be able to generate a URL from a route + data.

Comment: Yes I use T4MVC because it's easy. I can redirect using the more intuitive method syntax than having to put all of the route parameters / method args in a dictionary. However, T4MVC only generates a `RedirectToAction` extension method that accepts an `ActionResult` arg. It does not pre-compile in all of your parameters/route values. You can always look at the source to see how they do it, then mimic it.

Comment: Yeah, I've been incorporating ideas from their template into the solution where I can sneak it in.

Comment: So, I've figured out the issue; my example above didn't fully expose the problem; it seems that removing route values from the middle of the pattern causes a route not found error. I'm just going to go ahead and add a new route for this guy to fix the issue and move on. Marking as answer!

Comment: Right. MVC only wants you to have 1 optional parameter, and that optional parameter has to come at the end of the url. But that's not to say you can't use multiple routes to build up optional parameters.